# Javascript works on a jsfiddle but does not work when opening the local html on a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, here's the code, I had a problem with it but I got help with it in another question I had, so it should work.

What the code is supposed to do - when you click on the first picture = fade out and then bring the first picture from a string, then the second and the third with the in/out fade effect, when it you click on the picture while it is the last one, it resets to the original picture.

So here's the code, if you paste the javascript code with a src to the original picture to Jsfiddle with links to the same pictures = it will work, but not using the browser with local paths (which are correct).

It could be something in the HTML, though it wouldn't let me add it (it's kinda long anyways)

Here's the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageName = ["images/head4.jpg", "images/head3.jpg", "images/head.jpg"];    
    var indexNum = 0;

    $("#head1").click(function() {
        $("#head1").fadeOut(300, function() {
            $("#head1").load(function() {
                $("#head1").fadeIn(500);
            });
            $("#head1").attr("src", imageName[indexNum]);
            indexNum++;
            if (indexNum > 2) {
                indexNum = 0;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a case of finding the difference between your local copy and that on JSFiddle. Have you checked the console for errors? Are the versions of jQuery the same?

Comment: can you provide the JSfiddle you created?

Comment: [`.load` is an AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/load/), and therefore will not work outside of a web server.

Comment: One the first click it does the fade in/out effect and then loads up nothing, it should load the next picture, there's the .load event that is supposed to wait for the other image to load before to fix loading time. I believe you are correct and that AJAX function is messing it up... is there a way I can view it outside a web server to make sure it works or just rely on Jsfiddle?

Comment: What does the console say? Any error messages?

Comment: No errors in the console both on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery(a Javascript library), so you need to make sure to include the jQuery library in your HTML head tag like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I see what youre trying to do. The `.load` function should go after you're src attachment. Try this:

```
<body>
    <img id="head1" src="" onclick="clickfunction(this)" />
</body>
<script>
    var imageName = ["images/head4.jpg", "images/head3.jpg", "images/head.jpg"];
    var indexNum = 0;
    function clickfunction(curr) {
        $(curr).fadeOut(300, function() {
            $(this).remove();

            $('<img id="head1" onclick="clickfunction(this)" src="' + imageName[indexNum] + '" />').load(function() {
                $("body").append($(this));

                $("#head1").fadeIn(500);
                indexNum++;

                if (indexNum > 2) {
                    indexNum = 0;
                }
            });


        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ok just making sure. Many beginners forget that. I will continue looking at your problem